# Unix command for replacing distinct strings

Tags: regex, shell, unix, sed

I have this sed command:

```
sed 's/old/new/g' file.txt
```

but it also replaces the old inside the string 'folder'. how can i replace the string if there is not a character at it's left or right?

Answer (score 3):

If not picky, inserting blanks on both sides will work for you.

```
sed 's/ old / new /g' file.txt
```

Comment: Doesn't work at the beginning or end of the string. Doesn't work with any other forms of whitespace. Doesn't work with other word-terminating characters. That's a whole lot of "not picky".

Comment: \<...\> -- mark word boundaries, the upper one should be right.

Comment: That's true for GNU sed, but not specified by POSIX. (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sed.html)

Answer (score 2):

Use `\b`:

`'s/\bold\b/new/g'`

and I usually stick to perl:

`perl -pi -e 's/\bold\b/new/g' file.txt`

Comment: That `\b` *only* is guaranteed to work for perl; it's not supported by POSIX-standard sed. Thus, it's not a matter of usual habit, but necessity for anyone wanting to use this answer and be reasonably confident it'll work.

Comment: OP is not doing an in-place replacement.  Using `-i` in your Perl command line makes it dangerously non-equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

To be compatible with versions of sed not supporting the PCRE word-boundary extension, you need to emulate the effect of that extension yourself:

```
sed -r 's@(^|[^[:alpha:]])old($|[^[:alpha:]])@\1new\2@g'
```

Comment: I wonder if the `[[:space:]]` should be `[^[:alpha:]]` or `[^[:alnum:]]`?  Punctuation as well as space should probably be allowed as a delimiter.  Nevertheless, this is a reliable, albeit verbose, approach.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Good call; adopted.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/\<old\>/new/g' file
```

Incidently, if you want the opposite (using GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\Bold\B/new/g' file
```

Comment: The first form is also non-POSIX (but supported in GNU sed among others).